# ImportError: cannot import name ScrapyFileLogObserver

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I try to test the scrapy log with ScrapyFileLogObserver. In my source code, I correctly set the package to use:

> from scrapy.log import ScrapyFileLogObserver

but i've got this error when I launch my spider:

> from scrapy.log import ScrapyFileLogObserver
>
> ImportError: cannot import name ScrapyFileLogObserver

for information I use the last version of scrapy (Scrapy 1.0.1).
How I can fixe my bug ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 1.0 Scrapy's logging system [was completely rewritten](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1060), there is no `ScrapyFileLogObserver` anymore. Instead, Scrapy now [uses twisted's `PythonLoggingObserver` directly](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/fa1c25c84088ac6415e9dc82a7e79249624a737c/scrapy/utils/log.py#L87):

```
observer = twisted_log.PythonLoggingObserver('twisted')
observer.start()
```